# How To Use A QR Code To Start A Mobile App?

Tags: google-maps, mobile, qr-code

Does anyone know of a good way to create a QR code that will launch an app on any mobile device?

In our case we are looking to setup a QR code that will launch the Google Maps app...and...open a specific business listing.

Unfortunately, the only way to ask a mobile user to post a rating and review on a Google map listing is through the Google's map app.  Sending a mobile user to the listing's URL in a web browser on any mobile device does not give them the option to post a rating and review.  It has to be done through the Google Maps app.

Thanks for any ideas and feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is basically that a QR code can link to whatever a URL can link to. If you can make a hyperlink that opens Google Maps to the place you want, just put it in a QR code.

In fact, Android apps like Maps will specially handle links to Google Maps instead of the browser. So, yes in general. Whether Maps supports exactly the linking you want, I'm not sure. See: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3727220?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

The only thing a QR code will do is allow the user to easily scan a string into the device.  The QR code itself can contain information pertaining to what it IS, and the device will make suggestions accordingly.  But you cannot tell the device what to do.

So, in your case, all you can do is specify that the QR code is of type "URL", and include your entire string so Google Maps knows what to do with it.  The device will suggest to the user that Maps or a browser can be used, then pass that information along.